# Why collapse/expend dont work after adding new block?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Why my js code dont work? It worked before but when I added next block it dont work:

`<div class="collapse" id="collapse-block">`

I have collapse block (`id='collapse-block'`) which has 3 other collapse blocks inside. This js code works for button (`id='expand-collapse'`) which will *expand/collapse* blocks inside div (`id='blocks'`)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#expand-collapse').on('click', function() {
    var allCollapsed = true;
    $('#blocks .collapse').each(function(i, block) {
      if ($(block).hasClass('show')) {
        allCollapsed = false;
      }
    });
    $('#blocks .collapse').each(function(i, block) {
      if (allCollapsed) {
        $(block).collapse('show');
      } else {
        $(block).collapse('hide');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-block" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-block">OPEN/CLOSE</button>

    <button id='expand-collapse' type="button">OPEN/CLOSE BLOCKS</button>
  </div>

  <div class="card-block">
    <div class="collapse" id="collapse-block">
      <div id="blocks">
        <div class="list-group">

          <div class="list-group-item">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#block-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="block-1">FIRST BLOCK</a>
            <div class="collapse block" id="block-1">
               FIRST BLOCK
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="list-group-item">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#block-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="block-2">SECOND BLOCK</a>
            <div class="collapse block" id="block-2">
              SECOND BLOCK
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="list-group-item">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#block-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="block-3">THIRD BLOCK</a>
            <div class="collapse block" id="block-3">
              THIRD BLOCK
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per javascript standard, whenever you modify DOM, add or remove children, the event gets removed, you will have to add event again. that's issue here. I guess.

**Edit**

Modifying innerHTML causes the content to be re-parsed and DOM nodes to be recreated, losing the handlers you have attached. Appending elements as in the first example doesn't cause that behavior, so no re-parsing has to occur, since you are modify the DOM tree explicitly.

Another good way to handle this is to use insertAdjacentHTML(). For example:

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<br>')
```

Comment: Please add more information in your answer codes/snippets.

Comment: Well, ok but I am little bit comfused cause in js I wrote  `#blocks .collapse` which mean that all collapse blocks (in my case 3 block) inside div (id='blocks'). That div (id='blocks') inside main collapse block. So what can you say about my js?

Comment: can you provide pen? I will fix this for you. :-) and don't down vote. I am helping you.

Comment: I just want you to explain it more... nothing more.. cool.. :)

Comment: can you provide pen?

Comment: It was not me who vote down. Dont worry about me =) I am not good in editing of stackoverflow`s code snippet.

Comment: create fiddle or pen and provide link.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a reference to the Bootstrap script or Collapse.js

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

- [Bootstrap Scripts](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-cdn)
- [Collapse.js](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/)

Comment: I use bootstrap 4 alpha 6 version, also I add it in code. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are not added bootstrap css in your code, I think that's the problem

refer it like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

Working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qcdk68et/

Answer (score 0):

SORRY! It was my fault! I just forget to add js code file inside html. Question is closed.